# How to verify if a exported gpg key is a public or a private one

Tags: gnupg

If I've exported a gpg key using the command line, how can I verify if the exported key is a public one? I'm interested in both, a binary format and the armored format as well. I'm just a little bit scared to accidentally publish my private key. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

Run on the command line:

```
gpg the-keyfile
```

With `the-keyfile` being the `.asc` (armored) or `.pgp` (binary) file. The output will either start with `sec` (secret available) or `pub` (public key only). This is a successful export of a secret key:

```
sec  [more key details]
ssb  [more subkey details]
```

And this for a public key:

```
pub  [more key details]
sub  [more subkey details]
```

Note that exporting the secret key also implies the public key (one can derive the public from the secret).